# Java MethodDeclaration ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration finding class names

Tags: java, method-declaration, javaparser

I'm using the MethodDeclaration for a java parser that reads in source code but I'm having some problems. I can't see any methods which give me the class that this belongs to. Does a method exist for this or do I need to look in the java parser to try and create a way that will attach each MethodDeclaration to it's ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration .

I either need a way of detecting if a MethodDeclaration belongs to a class or I need a way of getting all of the methods in a ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration.

edit to make this more clear:

```
MethodDeclaration m = oldMethodDeclaration ; //where oldMethodDeclaration is already defined method declaration
```

I need a way to find the class that "m" belongs to. In the following example it will return "ClassName"

ie

```
    public class ClassName{
public void oldMethodDeclaration (){
}

}
```

Alternatively if I have

```
ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration ClassName;
```

is it possible for me to find a list of method names attached to it?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Please provide a SSCCE http://sscce.org/

Comment: added more information

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using JavaParser.

So to get the enclosing class for a MethodDeclaration:

```
TypeDeclaration t = (TypeDeclaration) m.getParentNode();
```

To visit methods of a ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration:

```
c.accept(new VoidVisitorAdapter<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void visit(MethodDeclaration n, Void arg) {
        System.out.println("Method name: " + n.getName());
    }
}, null);
```

I just printed the method names. I assume that gives you the necessary information to write a visitor to do something else with the MethodDeclarations.